# How to insert return value of one SQL command into another table using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have two servers hosting two different sites with two separate databases. However, some of the data needs to be shared - so there's a CRON that runs to copy that data from the first site to the second site. These two sites used to run on the same server, but now we have separated them so I'm attempting to amend the PHP to be able to handle this.

Here is the code where I'm encountering the problem:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM site1.events";
$events = mysql_query($sql, $site1db);  

$sql = "INSERT INTO site2.events SELECT * FROM $events";
$doIt = mysql_query($sql, $site2db);
```

Now I know that the `SELECT * FROM site1.events` is successful, but it cannot insert into the second site and I'm not seeing any sort of error. I've never written PHP before (this is a legacy task) so if it's something that's been covered before - do point me in the right direction.

Please note that `site2.events` is truncated before these commands so no compare is necessary.

Comment: Use `mysqli` instead of `mysql`. Not too sure how it handles mutliple servers but you could have a look at Federated tables.

Comment: `$events` is a mysql resource and I don't think you can use it as a string, however you can write ` * FROM ($sql)` since `$sql` is a string. Please notice that you're using `mysql_` which is deprecated and consider using `mysqli_` as @Coloco suggested or `PDO`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to do a row by row compare and copy. What you are attempting to do right now cannot work. You could use `INSERT IGNORE INTO site2.events (SELECT * FROM site1.events)` if the databases run on the same server and the database user can access both databases. The downside of this, the primary keys would have to be identical or you will miss data.

A better alternative would be to simply have site1 do a callback containing all info for that event to site2 at the moment a new event is added.

Comment: Thanks, I feared I would have to do the row by row insert but was hoping for a nicer solution.

Comment: The nicer solution is to modify your sites to inform eachother of events and having them instantly add it to the database. That way, you have no more data missing from sites until your cron syncs the database and you won't have to do a row by row comparison.

Comment: That isn't possible with the server setup we have unfortunately